# How to estimate the bias of a estimator of an unknown length?

Tags: bias, unbiased-estimator

Let's say I have a ruler of unknown length L. I then measure n objects with the ruler, obtaining a sample x1,..xn.
If an object is longer than the ruler, I'll register xi=L.
I want an unbiased estimator of L.
MAX(x1,...xn) seems like a reasonable, yet biased, place to start. Is there a way to estimate the bias of MAX(X)?

EDIT 1
I'm looking for a general solution to the question, regardless of the underlying ditribution of the measured objects. Perhaps the answer will need to involve assumptions on the distribution, but that's part of the thought process I'm seeking.
The ruler is precise.
If xi is longer than L, I'll only know that the registered measure for xi is L.

Comment: If you assume a distribution for the $x_i$, e.g. iid Uniform on [0, L], you can get an expression for the bias.

Comment: When you "register" that $x_i=L$, do you also record the fact that the object was longer than the ruler?  How are the objects selected?  (For instance, are they taken from a standard set of objects of graduated lengths?)  Are the object lengths known beforehand?  Is the ruler known to be accurate or not?

Comment: Edited my original question. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: If all your objects are always shorter than L, you can't estimate bias of MAX($x_i$). You need to know something about the distribution of object sizes.

Comment: The solutions will be quite different, depending on what you assume about the $x_i$. For instance, if you assume nothing about them then it's easy to show there is no unbiased estimator at all, whereas if you assume at least one of the $x_i$ is certainly greater than $L$, then the maximum obviously is unbiased. Thus, if you want more than a general set of (possibly conflicting) answers, it would behoove you to be as specific as possible about how the $x_i$ are selected in this experiment.

Comment: Actually, I think you gave me the answer I was looking for. Which is, it will depend on the assumptions. Can you prove what you said, that no assumptions on the distribution of x means no unbiased estimator exist? What if I told you that x is distributed uniformly between 0 and L+k? Can you use that information to come up with a quantity q to add to MAX(X) and make it unbiased?

Comment: @ADJ: To prove that it depends on assumptions, juist make two different distributional assumptions and show the answer differ ...